# How to add an html entity with Reflex.Dom?

Tags: reflex

As it should be `text "&copy;` is rendered escaped. How then should I render the © [html entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity) unescaped with [Reflex.Dom](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex-dom)?

Comment: Have you tried just putting the character in code, directly? It's unicode after all, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just use `text "copyright ©"`. No need to use HTML codes :)

Comment: Thanks for this workaround. I'd still like to know how to output html entities with reflex dom.

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. There is a function `_staticDomBuilderEnv_shouldEscape`on StaticDomBuilderEnv but I don't know if you can access it and set it only for the node you want to manipulate (probably not). I'd look at `el'`which gives you access to the node itself and then try to manipulate that node with the GHCJS-DOM api.